# Tips on ways to mark important equations/statements in a thesis/paper

Tags: graphics, equations, boxes

I'm writing my masters thesis and in it I have a set of examples for different chapters which I separate from the rest of the thesis by a mdframed-box. Furthermore, I have a set of equation that are of great importance and I wish to mark them in some, other than an mdframed-box, way.

This could for example be to write them in another color or make a circle around them. None of those suggestions seem pretty though.

Comment: Something in the margin, like a `\dbend`, perhaps?

Comment: Well, I fear, there is no answer which will please anybody. The markup of equations/statements should comply with readability of text and not distract too much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two suggestions come to mind. One would be to display the equations and give them a special name instead of the usual equation number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:einstein}
  E=mc^2\tag{$\star$}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

would produce

[image]

The reader can see that this equation is special because of its special label. You can reference it using `\eqref{eqn:einstein}` in the usual way.

The other suggestion would be to stop putting a box around your examples and use the `amsthm` package to wrap them in an example environment like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\begin{document}
\begin{example}
 This is an example of a very important, more general result stated elsewhere.
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This would free up the use of frames for equations.

Neither of these suggestions may be exactly what you had in mind, but I think they are more in keeping with usual academic typesetting conventions than alternatives such as using colour.